# Calculating Averages and Determining Lowest and Highest Values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, average

I have split up a list with names and corresponding scores and have stored them in a dictionary called students. But with these scores, I have been asked to figure out the average score, minimum score and maximum score. I am a beginner and a student so a step by step explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
def getStatistics(students):

#  Initialize properly the values of the average score, minimum score, and maximum score. 
    average = 0
    lowest = True
    highest = True
    scoreTotal = 0
```

The reason why the variables above were labeled that way is because in my main function, which calls on this function, had a built in call with those names. But whenever I go to run the program, it doesn't print any of it.

```
#  loop through the dictionary, and
#  calculate the average score, the highest score and the lowest score
#  of the students in the dictionary.

    i = 0
    for grade in students:
        scoreTotal += grade[i]
        i = i + 1
    average = scoreTotal/i
    lowest = min(grade[i])
    highest = max(grade[i])

#  The function must return back the average, highest and lowest score.
   return average, highest, lowest
```

In the main function it had this: (the "nameToMarksMap" is the function from the previous part with the dictionary students)

```
 average, highest, lowest = getStatistics(nameToMarksMap)

 print "Average:", average, "Highest:", highest, "Lowest:", lowest
```

Nothing is being printed, can anyone explain why? I keep getting errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP is trolling.

Comment: "Trolling"? Is that a new "thing" these days, to troll on SO? Clearly kid is trying to learn something on Sunday afternoon... Look at her scores -  a nube.

Comment: Can you show us your list with two or three students?

Answer (score 0):

finish the function with

```
def getStatistics(students)
    ...
    # snip
    ...
    return average, highest, lowest
```